# Is it possible to predict future 2FA values given older values with timestamps?

Tags: security, authentication, math, google-authenticator

Is it safe to share `2FA` codes? I'm talking about `TOTP` like `Google Authenticator` or `Authy`.

For example, if i have code and generation time, is it possible to predict new codes?
What if i have more than 1 pair of code+time?

I think it's possible to predict new codes based on old information (code+time).

So if this is possible, how do I do it? Im looking for some algorithm.

Known Time period, time, code and secret length.

Example:

```
22:20:30 561918
22:21:00 161664
22:21:30 610130
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally, these 2FA generators usually work based on a [time-based one-time password algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm). Those algorithms work by using strong hash functions on a combination of two values: a shared secret and the current time increment, and specifically use a construction called [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) that’s known to be secure provided the underlying hash function is.

As a result, if someone could predict future outputs of your 2FA device by seeing some timestamps and outputs from the 2FA device, then they would either (1) have to know the shared secret or (2) be able to break the HMAC. Both of these are unlikely unless someone either has hacked Google or knows of attacks on HMAC or the underlying hash function in ways beyond what’s in the public literature.

In other words, you shouldn’t need to worry about someone guessing future values given past values, though I’d still advise against giving out old values because you shouldn’t be giving out 2FA values to anyone except the site you’re logging into. :-)

Comment: Thanks! But how to do that? And how many pairs (code+time) needed to predict next codes? Im looking for this algorithm.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted my answer. There isn’t a known algorithm for predicting 2FA passwords generated this way because it’s designed to be resistant to such algorithms.

Comment: @templatetypedef If someone or knows my secret key then can he predict my future OTPs

Comment: Yes, that’s true. But the OP is specifically referring to the case where the OTP values from previous rounds are known and the secret key isn’t.

Comment: @templatetypedef Does it mean that if someone has my secret key then he can get my OTP even before it actually occurs on my device that is get the OTP before that time occurs on my device.